# Parse remote file with FasterCSV

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv, import, fastercsv

I'm trying to parse the first 5 lines of a remote CSV file. However, when I do, it raises `Errno::ENOENT` exception, and says:

`No such file or directory - [file contents]` (with [file contents] being a dump of the CSV contents

Here's my code:

```
  def preview
    @csv = []
    open('http://example.com/spreadsheet.csv') do |file|
      CSV.foreach(file.read, :headers => true) do |row|
        n += 1
        @csv << row
        if n == 5
          return @csv
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The above code is built from what I've seen others use on Stack Overflow, but I can't get it to work.

If I remove the `read` method from the file, it raises a `TypeError` exception, saying:

```
can't convert StringIO into String
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe I'm not aware of this, but to my knowledge, FasterCSV cannot download the document on the fly and parse it - save it to your hard drive first

Answer (score 0):

Foreach expects a filename. Try parse.each

Comment: Thanks - though when I tried foreach (which seems more elegant, given that I want to load a file anyway), I get the following error: `No such file or directory - http://example.com/spreadsheet.csv` Is there some better way to write this?

Comment: You could save the url as a file first I suppose.

Comment: I realize this is getting a little off topic, but I'm using Carrier Wave to hold these files in s3. Passing in the carrier wave object didn't work either - is there a different tact i should take? Using heroku, so i can't download the file to my server.

Comment: In that case use parse.each, I don't really see it as less elegant anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually pass each line to CSV for parsing:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

def preview(file_url)
    @csv = []
    open(file_url).each_with_index do |line, i|
        next if i == 0 #Ignore headers
        @csv << CSV.parse(line)
        if i == 5
            return @csv
        end
    end
end

puts preview('http://www.ferc.gov/docs-filing/eqr/soft-tools/sample-csv/contract.txt')
```